# Sequelize - save a list of objects

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new in nodejs and Sequelize. What I am trying to do is just to save(update, not create) a list of users that their ids already exist in my DB. I tried to do something like this:

```
Modles.User.save([{id: 1, name: Michael}, {id: 2, name: David}]).then(function({
   console.log("users saved");
});
```

I know this is not the right way to do it, but I didn't find information about how to do it.
Someone can help me?

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update those records one by one if you want to use different update values for each of them.

```
Models.User.findById(1).then(function(user){
    user.update({ name: 'Michael' }).then(function(firstUser){
        // updated instance of user
    });
});
```

You would have to do the same operation as above for the second user in order to update it's name also.